# How to write CodeIgniter controller URL in jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying an ajax call in CodeIgniter but confused how to write controller and its function name in url.

```
$.ajax({              
     type : "POST",
     url  : "<?php echo base_uri(); ?>/application/controllers/controllerName/FunctionName",
});
```

Here I am writing the whole path but it doesn't seem right.
Is this ok or is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/controllerName/FunctionName"
      });
```

OR

```
      $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url  : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/controllerName/FunctionName"
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you should be able to call it like so:

```
$.ajax({

    type : "POST",
    url  : "/controllerName/FunctionName",

});
```

But this depends a little bit on your url structure and whether or not you got rid of `index.php` in the url structure. In that case the url would be `"/index.php/controllerName/FunctionName"`

Answer (score 1):

Write some where at the top of the page e.g in the header section the following js code.

NOTE: this code should be above your ajax method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
    function site_url(url){
        var bu = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
        url = (url)?url:"";
        return bu + "index.php/" + url;
    }
</script>
```

then you can write your ajax method as follow:

```
$.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url  : site_url("controllerName/FunctionName"),

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
url  : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/controllerName/FunctionName",
```

---

**Errors in your code**

```
url  : "<?php echo base_uri(); ?>/application/controllers/controllerName/FunctionName",
                          ^1           ^2         ^3
```

1. its should be `base_url` not `base_uri`
2. and 3.  `application` folder will not use in URL. It is a file structer.  Not belong to URL.

Comment: great @Abdulla Nilam almost you respond quickly on most of question ;)

Comment: @MuhammadUsman i don't get enough time to come online. Just an visit most of time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine,Because I have not removed index.php till yet.

```js
$.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/ajax/hello",
          type:'post',
          data:{
                  "name":name,
                  "email":email,
                  "phone":phone
                },
         success:function(data){
           $("#display").html(data);
       }
        });
```